# I want to remove completed orders from a list

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-session, hibernate-restrictions

In my App I have List of Orders. I want to remove completed orders from that list. that means the `status = Completed`.There are more two status.
so I try this.

```
Session s = HibernateSession.getSession();
Criteria c = HibernateSession.createCriteria(s, Orders.class);
c.add(Restrictions.not(
Restrictions.in("status","Completed")));  //compile error...
List<Orders> orders = c.list();
```

But above line I got Compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier to add `.ne()`

> Apply a "not equal" constraint to the named property
>   <sub>[~Java doc~](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#ne(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))</sub>

---

```
c.add(Restrictions.ne("status", "Completed"));
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the error it take a argument of list or collections. so it must be

```
c.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("status",new String[] {"Completed"})));
```